# glob.sync not matching ../path/*.js patterns

Tags: node.js, debugging, path, glob

Hey I am trying to iterate through a set of files using glob.sync in node js.
It works perfectly fine for

```
glob.sync('./path/*.js').forEach(function(file){
    //code
});
```

but I want to move this file into another folder and then do this

```
glob.sync('../path/*.js').forEach(function(file){
    //code
});
```

The code fails here and callback is not getting executed, is this not supported in glob or am I doing a mistake
Please help

Comment: Are you sure there is js files there? Have you checked for typos?

Comment: Yes they are there, else it will not work for ./ also na, I am able to get files for ./ but ../ after moving it into another directory

Comment: Probably you don’t realize, that `glob` resolve paths relative to `process.cwd()` (current working directory) unlike `require`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Thankyou so much, I got my mistake, as you told, I had to give ./ for glob and ../ for other requires outside glob, one file was missing coz glob looked from cwd